# how to avoid having a '\' cutting off a row when printing large tables?

Tags: python, pandas

In Python 3.5 when printing a large table out, I did not code anything like '\n', but I always got something like this:

```py
      RULE_PACKAGE SCORE RISK_TYPE  RULE_TYPE         CREATE_TIME  \
  612      评分卡规则包3  3.00      None          1 2016-11-18 00:14:27   
  613      评分卡规则包3  1.00      None          1 2016-11-18 00:14:27   
  614      评分卡规则包3  1.00      None          1 2016-11-18 00:14:27   
  615      评分卡规则包3  1.00      None          1 2016-11-18 00:14:27   
  616      评分卡规则包3  2.00      None          1 2016-11-18 00:14:27   
  617      评分卡规则包3  2.00      None          1 2016-11-18 00:14:27   
  618      评分卡规则包3  1.00      None          1 2016-11-18 00:14:27   
  621      评分卡规则包3  0.00      None          1 2016-11-18 00:14:27   
  622      评分卡规则包3  0.00      None          1 2016-11-18 00:14:27   

              UPDATE_TIME  
  612 2016-11-18 00:14:27  
  613 2016-11-18 00:14:27  
  614 2016-11-18 00:14:27  
  615 2016-11-18 00:14:27  
  616 2016-11-18 00:14:27  
  617 2016-11-18 00:14:27  
  618 2016-11-18 00:14:27  
  621 2016-11-18 00:14:27  
  622 2016-11-18 00:14:27
```

I want each column to be sticked in one row, like a normal column. What should i do?

Thanks,

Comment: How do you expect to scroll when using a terminal? Use [Jupyter](http://jupyter.org/), and it will give you a single row.

Comment: thanks to both of you, it provides a way of solution.thanks.